# 'Hosting' users domain names on a CMS

Tags: php, wordpress, dns, content-management-system, web-hosting

I've carried out quite a bit of research and searching to find out how CMS and web applications such as Wordpress.com work when it comes to mapping user domains.

As you may be aware, users can add their custom domain onto a Wordpress.com website - this is what I'm looking to achieve for my own service I'm building. It's code base is PHP with a MySQL backend.

How is this done? My best guess was through a database lookup and a redirect to the correct wordpress subdomain. If anyone has any ideas on this I would really appreciate your input. Thanks!

Comment: "My best guess was through a database lookup and a redirect to the correct wordpress subdomain." Pretty much this. With smaller numbers of users you could handle it in your webserver's config, as well.

Comment: Thanks, the next task would be cloaking the domain to always have the users custom domain - `mywebsite.com/about` instead of `user.webapp.com/about`

Comment: WordPress's code is open source and includes all the functionality you're referring to.